# how to extract features when observations and feature set are almost equal?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I need to do a regression where I have in total 750 observations and nearly 500 features. I am struggling to come up with feature engineering technique that gives top 10 or 15 non col-linear features with enough predicting power. I have used things like Recursive feature elimination but I do not get anything meaningful out of it. On a cross validated test I sometimes get an R squared of -10. Can someone please give me some pointers on what algorithm/technique to used when dealing with such problems?
I am using python as my chosen platform for analysis.

Thanks

Comment: What do you get with an untuned random forest on all features? It's often a good benchmark.

Comment: I used automated machine learning which used gradient boosting with nearly 100 features selected based on my understanding of the business domain and I got an R squared of 98.5 which is crystal clear case of over fitting.